# If $ |x-y| \leq \epsilon $ and $ |z-w| \leq \delta$ then $|xz - yw| \leq \epsilon |z| + \delta |x| + \epsilon \delta $.

Tags: real-analysis

**To Prove** Let $\epsilon, \delta > 0 $. If $ |x-y| \leq \epsilon  $ and $ |z-w| \leq \delta$ then $|xz - yw| \leq \epsilon |z| + \delta |x| + \epsilon \delta $.

**My solution** Since $|x-y| \leq \epsilon $ we also have $ |w||x-y| \leq \epsilon |w| $ i.e., $ |wx-wy| \leq \epsilon |w|$. Similarly, $ |x||z-w| \leq  |x|\delta $ or $ |xz-xw| \leq |x|\delta $.
So, $|xw-yw+xz-xw| \leq |xw-yw| + |xz-xw| \leq \epsilon |w| + \delta |x| $. Thus, $ |xz - yw| \leq \epsilon |w| + \delta |x|$ .

**Question** Where did I go wrong in my solution because I am missing the factor $\epsilon \delta $?

Comment: You approach is correct, but note that they have obtained an $\epsilon |z|$ term instead of an $\epsilon |w|$ term. Simply expand $|w| \leq |w - z| + |z|$. This is just a technicallity I think, if you want to prove continuity of the product (i.e. $|xz - yw|$ is small), you are done with just what you did.

Comment: Since you proved that xz−yw|≤ϵ|w|+δ|x|, we know that ϵ,δ>0ϵ,δ>0, wouldn't that implicitly mean that |xz−yw|≤ϵ|z|+δ|x|+ϵδ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you just did not finish the proof:

$$\epsilon|w|-\epsilon|z|\leq\epsilon|z-w|= \epsilon\delta$$

Hence

$$\epsilon |w| + \delta |x|\leq\epsilon|z| + \delta |x|+\epsilon\delta$$